# Is mercury still found in modern e-waste?

Tags: recycling, waste, toxic-chemicals

Is mercury still found in modern e-waste? I need an authoritative reference, please. I did try to research it on my own, but got conflicting information.

Comment: Take a look at [RoHS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_of_Hazardous_Substances_Directive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of mercury in electronics devices that end up producing e-waste is small but present in some components.

Though not widely used now, cathode ray tube (CRT) monitors contain mercury as do some button batteries, [liquid crystal display (LCD) monitors](https://www.epa.gov/mercury/mercury-consumer-products) and [screens](https://itechxpressinc.com/cracked-lcd-screen-can-be-hazardous-know-these-things-beforehand/) and some [printed circuit boards and switches](https://mcbia.com/ewasterecycle.com/?page_id=228).